# kotlin/ktor session does not persist (some) values across requests

Tags: kotlin, ktor

#### Kotlin/Ktor web application

I have a standard web application which uses the session in Ktor to keep some values. The problem is that this session object keeps some values between requests **but not all**. After loading a specific page and by looking at the client cookie, I can see that the last two fields are not set, although many others keep their values through requests.

```
actTab=#i1
&email=#smyname@domain.abc
&locale=#sen-US
&nextTab=#i1
&nrConnections=#i0
&nrUsers=#i0
&ntfs=#m#sYour profile was successfully updated.=#sINF
&oid=#sORG#1234567890
&uid=#sUSR#0987654321
&wsName=#s
&wsPk=#s
```

Any ideas anyone? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

#### My Solution

To start with, I was not able to find the problem yet. After some online search, I went on to try a more server side session management by using Ktor `SessionStorageMemory` feature. Instead of passing all session content to the browser and back, with this only the session id is passed in the HTTP requests.

This way of dealing with the session object solved the problem I had. Despite the issues with automatic session invalidation this is the solution for the time being as this question can also be solved at a later stage.

Any contributions from anyone on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: **update**: recently I came back to this issue and upon removing the `SessionStorageMemory` option, tried the web application and everything was just normal... could have been something internal to Ktor? Can't really answer... but now it is just fine.